# Clickable link in tooltip of Highcharts

Tags: javascript, html, url, highcharts, tooltip

I have tooltips having a list of data in it. I want each data to be a link which redirects to the page for that particular data. Now the problem with Highcharts tooltip is that it changes with respective to the x-axis. As soon as x-axis changes, the tooltip changes to the respective component on the x-axis. So in case i get my tooltip working with links, as soon as i move to click the link, the tooltip changes. To tackle this I figured out a way to fix the tooltip as soon as you click on the tooltip. Here is the code for that.

```
plotOptions: {
        series: {
            cursor: 'pointer',
            point: {
                events: {
                    click: function() {
                        if (cloneToolTip)
                        {
                            chart.container.firstChild.removeChild(cloneToolTip);
                        }
                        cloneToolTip = this.series.chart.tooltip.label.element.cloneNode(true);
                        chart.container.firstChild.appendChild(cloneToolTip);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

But even then i need to make the links in the tooltip which are clickable. I saw some threads on stackoverflow where they have done it, but its not working there also. It shows them as links but they're not clickable. Posting a working example here.

[JSFiddle working example](http://jsfiddle.net/SeCAB/214/)

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit 1:-
These are all the series that i have. May be the tooltip is getting hidden because of some other graph.

```
series: [{
        type: 'column',
        name: 'Success',
        color: '#7deda2',
        yAxis: 1,
        tooltip: {
            pointFormatter: function(){
              return "Success: " + this.y + "%" + "<br />" + "Success docs: " + toolTipSuccess[this.series.data.indexOf( this )] + "<br />";
            }
        },
        data: [{{barSuccess}}]
    }, 
    {
      type: 'scatter',
      name: 'Incidents',
      yAxis: 1,
      data: scatterData,
      color: '#FFAE19',
      tooltip: {
            pointFormatter: function() {
              var string = '';
              Highcharts.each(toolTip[this.series.data.indexOf(this)], function(p) {
                string += '<a href="http://www.google.com">' + p + '</a><br>'
              });
              return string + "<br />";
            }
          },
    },
    {
        type: 'spline',
        name: 'Failure',
        tooltip: {
            pointFormatter: function(){
              return "Failure: " + this.y + "%" + "<br />" + "Failure docs: " + toolTipFailure[this.series.data.indexOf( this )] + "<br />";
            }
        },
        data: [{{barFailure}}],
        marker: {
            lineWidth: 3,
            lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[8],
            fillColor: 'red'
        }
    },
    {{#if lu}}
       {
        type: 'spline',
        name: 'Unknown',
        tooltip: {
            pointFormatter: function(){
              return "Unknown: " + this.y + "%" + "<br />" + "Unknown docs: " + toolTipUnknown[this.series.data.indexOf( this )] + "<br />";
            }
        },
        data: [{{barUnknown}}],
        marker: {
            lineWidth: 3,
            lineColor: 'blue',
            fillColor: '#87CEFA'
        }
    }
    {{/if}}
```

Answer (score 3):

Tooltip's useHTML property should be defined in the global tooltip property - but for `<a>` is not sufficient. Changing pointerEvents attribute is necessary - you can see the issue here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5722

```
tooltip: {
  useHTML: true,
  style: {
    pointerEvents: 'auto'
  }
},
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/SeCAB/216/

Comment: It seems to be working in your case. When i click on the tooltip, after sometime the data in the tooltip disappears. I don't know why it is happening. May be because i have multiple charts. I'll update the code in the question. Please take a look.