# Allow text input (write-back) from highchart tooltip

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to allow text input to be specified via tooltip. I was able to add an input box by setting useHTML = true and made it clickable by setting pointerEvents to auto. I still can't input any text into the box. Is it possible?

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SeCAB/670/

```
tooltip: {
  useHTML: true,
  style: {
    pointerEvents: 'auto'
  }
},
```

taken from [Clickable link in tooltip of Highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40012916/clickable-link-in-tooltip-of-highcharts)

The input box below url in the tooltip is not editable (cannot input any text)

Comment: Could you add a live demo of what you already have? For example use jsFiddle. Thanks!

Comment: Added the live demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highcharts by default prevent focus on input. You can workaround this issue by focusing inputs.

#### Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/f6hzrxj8/

#### Snippet:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target && e.target.classList.contains('tooltip-input')) {
    e.target.focus();
  }
})
```

**Note:** Event delegation is needed because your inputs are dynamic.